# Saving with PlayerPref problems

Tags: c#

I'm having troubles saving how much of an item I have in my game. Right now I have it so the price goes up the more items you buy, that works, but every time I reset the game, the count goes back to 0, while the price acts as if the count is at a higher number.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ItemManager : MonoBehaviour {

public UnityEngine.UI.Text itemInfo;
public GPS gps;
public Click click;
public float cost;
public int tickValue;
public int count = 0;
public string itemName;
private float baseCost;
private Slider _slider;


void Start()
{

    Load ();
    baseCost = cost;
    _slider = GetComponentInChildren<Slider> ();
}

void Update()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Count", count);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Cost", cost);

    itemInfo.text = itemName + " (" + count + ") " + "\nCost: " + cost + "\nGold: " + tickValue + "/s";

    _slider.value = click.gold / cost * 100;

    if (_slider.value >= 100) {
        GetComponent<Image> ().color = buyColor;
    }else{
        GetComponent<Image>().color = standard;
    }
}

public void BuyItem()
{
    if (click.gold >= cost)
    {
        click.gold -= cost;
        count += 1;
        cost = Mathf.Round (baseCost + Mathf.Pow (2f, count));
    }
}

public void Load()
{
    count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Count");
    cost = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Cost");
}
}
```

I've tried to figure this our for hours, and I just don't know what to do with this.

Comment: I have a feeling that it has to do with the fact that you have 'public int count = 0' at the beginning of the file. Try having it initially null like your baseCost and set it equal to zero in your start method. Sorry I can't test it out for you. I'm on mobile.

Comment: Oh no! Don't save to player prefs in Update, which happens every frame! Have a `Save` function like your `Load` function, and save it only if the value changes.

Comment: @bpgeck I changed it back to 'public int count;' but that didn't work. I also did what Justin Markwell suggested, did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing you use PlayerPrefs.Save (); which is how you save the values so they are kept when the application is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are consistent with which GetInt or GetFloat you are using, on Public void load you are using GetInt for "Count", but in Update you are using SetFloat for both.

Comment: Thanks, I made it all the same. But that didn't fix it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say youre reseting your game?

Comment: Closing the game, like turning it off.

Answer (score -1):

As saboehnke said, you need to save the informations if you want it after reset the game. To do this, simple add PlayerPrefs.Save () after you set something as a PlayerPrefs.
But remember: if you want to save a resonable amount of information, consider use XML.